# What is the math behind equal-spacing divider tool?

Tags: geometry, golden-ratio

I want to know what is the math behind this tool,

[image]

the 10 point divider ([Full size image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0tKt.jpg)).

This tool is used to measure equidistant spaces and it's proportional, so you can scale it as much as you want. See [this page](http://www.mrcrook.com/blog/2016/1/30/weird-tools-2-10-point-divider) for its use drawing perspective grids.

I searched the internet but didn't find anything useful except for a [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) ruler.

[image]

I know that it measures 1 to 1.618 but how to keep it scalable?

Comment: I think this is one of the coolest oddball mechanical devices I've ever seen; hence the edit in the hopes of reopening! (Even though the current answer is quite nice)

Comment: @pjs36 thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never seen this device, but I would recognize the geometric principal anywhere. This tool relies on parallelograms to keep its fingers straight. Believe it or not, most of this device is mathematically redundant. To fully constrain the fingers, you only need the bottom three rows of joints.

Thanks to the [properties of parallelograms](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/geometry/quadrilaterals/properties-of-parallelograms), we can postulate that all of the parallelograms in a row are congruent, because all of their corresponding segments are parallel and of equal length (the distance between two joints). Because any two fingers are just extensions of the opposite sides of a parallelogram, they must be parallel and equally spaced.

As for the Golden Section Gauge, the same principal applies. In the image that you provided, $ \overline{AF}/\overline{BF} = 340/210 \approx \phi $. Parallelogram $ABEC$ keeps $ \overline{AC} \ || \ \overline{BE} $. [The Proportional Segments Theorem](http://ceemrr.com/Geometry1/ParallelSimilar/ParallelSimilar4.html) proves that $ \overline{AF}/\overline{BF} = \overline{FG}/\overline{HG} $, thus $ \overline{FG}/\overline{HG} \approx \phi $. The device is "scaleable", because this proof holds true regardless of the size of $ \angle{FAH} $.

Comment: Thanks man, you are awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for and the moment I read parallelograms, I smiled as of how beautiful and easy it's, yet I couldn't see it. Thank you very much.